# bison c++: error expected initializer before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm using flex and bison on C++ bur now I struggled.

The error that g++ throws is:

```
src/bison.tab.h:125: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
```

bison.tab.h is an auto generated file from bison yacc parser, the line that give me the error is

```
bison.tab.h:125: extern YYSTYPE yylval;
```

My bison.y

```
void yyerror(const char* error);    
#include "objects/tabla.h"    
#include "Node.h"    
#define YYSTYPE Node*    
#include "bison.tab.h"    
#include "lex.yy.c"
using namespace std;       
void yyerror(const char* error) {cout<<"*** "<<error<<endl; };        
Node* root;    
%}    
%nonassoc vacio
%tokens 
%start start    
%%
Grammar....
%%
main()
{   
    yyparse();
}
```

I don't know if here is the problem that i can't see...

Cheers,

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the preprocessed input (-E with g++) to check if macros aren't playing tricks on you.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that it's not recognising `Node` as a type name. Can you show us where `Node` is defined (presumably in `"Node.h"`)?

Comment: In addition to what @AProgrammer has said, take a look at `bison.tab.h` just before line 125. It could be that the actual error is there and not on line 125.

Answer (score 1):

`#define YYSTYPE Node*`

I think this line leads to the problem, and if you'd better use `%union` to customize node type, like

```
{% ... %}

%union {
    Node* node_type;
}

%type <node_type> ast_root
%type <node_type> something0
%type <node_type> something1

%%

ast_root: ....
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem really was I loose the reference to the namespace of the Node.